# Loss not changing no matter the learning rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have built a deep learning model, slightly similar to the VGG net. I'm using Keras with a Tensorflow backend. The model summary is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(180,320,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9,  activation='relu'))
```

I have tried different combinations of optimizer (SGD, Adam, etc.), loss (MSE, MAE, etc.), batch sizes (32 and 64). I have even experimented with learning rates ranging from 0.001 to 10000. But still, even after 20 epochs, for whichever loss function I use, the validation loss remains exactly the same. The training loss changes insignificantly. What am I doing wrong?

What my network should be trained to do: Given an input image, the network needs to predict a set of 9 real values which can be derived from this image.

Terminal output during training:

```
    Epoch 1/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 96s 20ms/step - loss: 133.6534 - mean_absolute_error: 133.6534 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 2/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 49s 10ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 3/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 4/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 5/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 6/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 7/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 8/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 9/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 10/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 11/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 12/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 13/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 50s 10ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 14/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 15/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 16/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 17/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 18/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 19/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 20/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 51s 11ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
    Epoch 21/100
    4800/4800 [==============================] - 50s 10ms/step - loss: 132.8033 - mean_absolute_error: 132.8033 - val_loss: 132.3744 - val_mean_absolute_error: 132.3744
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`relu`

Don't use relu carelessly! It has a constant zero region without gradients. It's totally normal for it to get stuck.

- The worst mistake is having relu at the final layer.

  - If you want outputs from 0 to infinite, use `'softplus'`.
  - If you want between 0 and 1 use `'sigmoid'`
  - If you want between -1 and +1 use `'tanh'`
- Your learning rates are **giant**. With relu, you need **small** learning rates:

  - Go for `0.0001` and below.
- Try other activations that don't get stuck
- Try adding a batch normalization before the activation (this way you're sure something will be above zero, no matter what):

  - This also allows you to have bigger learning rates

.

```
model.add(Conv2D(..... , activation='linear'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out. What should I use if I want my outputs to be from -ve infinite to +ve infinite?

Comment: You can use `'linear'` at the end... but I suggest you normalizer your outputs first, then choose a `'tanh'` or a `'sigmoid'`.

Comment: In my case it came with experience... I can't suggest books because I never used one...

Comment: Ok. Nice! How can I normalize my outputs? And how do I used the outputs of a model trained on these normalized outputs? I mean, how do unnormalize the outputs?

Comment: You can find the max value and divide everything by this max. And invert it by multiplying the same value.